# variable always equals zero

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi dear developers! I'm just wrote my first iphone game. But i have faced an information output problem below

```
myStr = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Best Score:", counter];
```

The variable "counter" each time changes value at hit in the enemy. But in the information output I receiving always a zero, like "Best Score: 0". Help to understand and fix that problem.

Class Texture & Sprite I've got from John Ward from www.karmatoad.co.uk

Some code here:

```
myStr = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Best Score:", counter];
_Texture = [[Texture alloc] initWithText: myStr fontSize:24];
_Sprite = [[Sprite alloc] initWithTexture: _Texture];
[_Sprite drawSprite];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have suggested, you are missing the placeholder for your variable. I just wanted to provide some background:

`NSString` supports the format characters defined for the ANSI C function `printf()`, plus `%@` for any object.

In format strings, a `%` character announces a placeholder for a value, with the characters that follow determining the kind of value expected and how to format it, i.e. [format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
myStr = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Best Score: %d", counter];
```

and %d is an integer type if counter is float

```
myStr = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Best Score: %f", counter];
```

Answer (score 1):

use below

```
myStr = [NSString  stringWithFormat:@"Best Score: %d", counter];
```